# What does this function do?

Tags: c++, c

I am reading a program which contains the following function, which is

```
int f(int n) {
    int c;
    for (c=0;n!=0;++c) 
        n=n&(n-1);
    return c;
}
```

I don't quite understand what does this function intend to do?

Comment: Which goes to show that `f` is a terrible name for this function.

Comment: A comment or two wouldn't have hurt, either.

Comment: The code looks bad, but after 30 seconds it appears rather elegant. And efficient. A good example of "why don't C programmers put more intention into their identifiers? Because they love to be cryptic enough to look powerful when they aren't.".

Comment: Impressive how fast good answers and comments show up here at Stackoverflow.

Comment: I approve of this code, I think I've had to hack together a few 'count the bits' routines before, but I think I'll use this next time.

Comment: I guess you get an "A" on this part of your homework assignment.

Comment: Everybody loves bit-twiddle! It's the finest form of discrete mathematics</sarcasm>

Comment: If you input 2 to this function it will return 1. Thats called Hacking!!

Comment: I suspect that this is a homework assignment or quiz question of some sort, hence the name "f".

Comment: You should simulate code like this by hand to see what it does, that way you'd learn more.

Comment: David's right. f() as a name screams homework or an interview question. Many of user297850's questions seem to be interview questions, so that's probably what this is.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It [counts number of 1's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer/109036#109036) in binary representation of n

Comment: I like how this wouldn't have needed to be asked if the function had been called `countBinaryOnes` instead of `f`. Also, +1.

Comment: +1. See 2a here - http://gurmeetsingh.wordpress.com/2008/08/05/fast-bit-counting-routines/

Comment: Coding elegance: A+. Coding clarity: F.

Comment: This kind of function not onlyt needs a good name but also a good comment block describing what it does. Even if the name was countBinaryOnes would you trust that is what it did?

Comment: @Jay, B+ perhaps. f(INT_MIN) invokes UB. Should be unsigned f(unsigned) IMHO.

Comment: Oh, and personally I would have written "n&=n-1" for brevity. On the other hand I probably wouldn't have used a FOR loop, as I avoid having the test refer to a different value from the increment. I find that potentially confusing.

Answer (score 6):

The function is INTENDED to return the number of bits in the representation of n. What is  missed out in the other answers is, that the function invokes undefined behaviour for arguments n < 0. This is because the function peels the number away one bit a time, starting from the lowest bit to the highest. For a **negative** number this means, that the last value of n before the loop terminates (for 32-bit integers in 2-complement) is 0x8000000. This number is INT_MIN and it is now used in the loop for the last time:

```
n = n&(n-1)
```

Unfortunately, INT_MIN-1 is a overflow and overflows invoke undefined behavior. A conforming implementation is not required to "wrap around" integers, it may for example issue an overflow trap instead or leave all kinds of weird results.

Comment: Counting set bits in a signed quantity is generally not what you want to do anyway. The function should just accept `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 5):

It is a (now obsolete) workaround for the lack of the POPCNT instruction in non-military cpu's.

Answer (score 4):

This counts the number of iterations it takes to reduce `n` to `0` by using a binary and.

Comment: Yes, but what is that number of iterations dependent on :P  Vlad hit it.

Comment: The answer is at most 1: n & 0

Comment: @Nick; good point.  I didn't think of that explanation, so I was just describing the mechanics rather than the intent.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `n = n & (n - 1)` is a bitwise operation which replaces the rightmost bit '1' to '0' in `n`.

For examle, take an integer 5 (0101). Then `n & (n - 1)` → `(0101) & (0100)` → `0100` (removes first '1' bit from right side).

So the above code returns **the number of 1's in binary form of given integer.**

Answer (score 1):

It shows a way how not to program(for the x86 Instruction set), using a intrinsic/inline assembler instruction is faster and better to read for something simple like this. (but this is only true for a x86 Architecture as far as i know, i don't know how's it about ARM or SPARC or something else)

Comment: What's the assembly instruction that does it on a Freescale HCS08? :P

Comment: I think you need to justify that a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be it tries to return the number of significant bits in n? (Haven't thought through it completely...)

Comment: Although I think @Vladimir's answer is technically accurate, I like this explanation best.

Comment: @Randolpho What? This answer is wrong.  Given the input 0b1000 it would return 1, not 4 (the number of significant binary digits--bits)

Comment: What does significant bits mean?

Comment: @Ammon: The minumum number of binary digits that is required to represent the value, i.e. the position (1-based counting) of the last non-zero bit counting from the LSB (from right).

Comment: @Nick T: Ahh, I see that now.

Comment: Significant digits are those that have meaning.  For integers represented in binary, the *in*significant digits are leading zeros.  Fixed/floats are a little different.

Comment: @Andreas: thanks. So the answer would be to replace the 4th line with `n >>= 1`.

Comment: Wow am I glad I mentioned that I had not thought about it until the end :)  right in the beginning :)

Comment: The number of **set** bits. :)