# whether the binary representation of a number is alternating bits eg. 10101010 , 1010 etc

Tags: c++, binary, bit-manipulation

So I had to find whether the binary representation of a number is alternating 1s and 0s.

Expected time complexity and space complexity are both O(1)

My Idea was first to find the 1's complement of the number(=n) ,  (lets say compl)

then if n (AND) compl  == 0 then the number's bin rep is alternating 1s and 0s

However it's not working properly

**This was the complement function (which I found yesterday)**

```
    int complement(int n){
        int noOfDigits = floor(log2(n))+1;
        return ((1<<noOfDigits) - 1)^n;
    }
```

**And here is the actual function's extract**

```
        if(n&complement(n) == 0)return true;
        else return false;
```

Comment: No don't use floating point to calculate integer values.

Comment: You only need a simple loop that checks each adjacent pair of bits to be unequal with `&` and `<<` or `>>`.

Comment: Your `complement` appears to be little more than bitwise negation. And of course `X & ~X` is always zero. Your approach tests every bit against itself; no attempt is made to compare e.g. bit 0 and bit 1, which is something you need to do in order to detect a pattern.

Comment: "_Expected time complexity and space complexity are both O(1)_" doesn't make any sense btw. In terms of what parameter is the complexity supposed to be measured? The number of bits in the type? Then it is obviously impossible, because each bit is always relevant to the output.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh yeah ! I just did some test runs on paper of my approach, I forgot that X & ~X is always 0. Thanks

Comment: [OT]: `if (cond) return true; else return false;` might simply be `return cond;`.

Comment: That `complement` function that you found is pretty much useless, but if you were going to do something like that you can use functions from the `<bit>` header to implement it properly

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with just 5 operations (depending on how you count operations but let's not argue about that):

```
bool is_alternating(uint32_t x)
{
    uint32_t y = x << 1;
    return (x & (y + (y | 3))) == x;
}
```

See the output [on ideone](https://ideone.com/mgdKAW).

Zero and one are included, because they are alternating patterns, though of length zero and one respectively (so they don't *look* alternating, but only because there are not enough bits to really show the pattern).

The pattern `(x & S) == x` is a common idiom to test whether `x` is a subset of `S`. Here, `S = y + (y | 3) = (x << 1) + ((x << 1) | 3)`.

What `S` is and what it means for `x` to be a subset of `S` is fairly complicated and I did not just randomly come up with it. This solution was found using an implementation of CEGIS (CounterExample Guided Inductive Synthesis), so computer-generated.

If `x` is even then *in that case* `S` is equivalent to `S = (x << 2) | 3`. Let's name the bits of `x` as `abcd0` (the zero is there because `x` is even), and therefore `S = abcd011`.

- `d0` is always a subset of `11`, any two bits are a subset of `11`.
- `cd` is a subset of `01` if and only if `c = 0`.
- `bc` is a subset of `d0` if and only if `b <= d and c = 0`
- `ab` is a subset of `cd` if and only if `a <= c and b <= d`

Now in order for `a` to be 1, `c` would also have to be 1 and it can't be, so `a = 0`. On the other hand `b` can be 1, namely if `d` is also 1. These patterns continue such that the bits at even positions (starting at index zero for the least significant bit) must all be zero, while the even bits can be 1 up to some point and as soon as one of them is zero then the remainder to the left must also all be zero.

If `x` is odd then *in that case* `S` is equivalent to `S = (x << 2) | 1`. Let's name the bits of `x` as `abcd1` (the one is there because `x` is odd), and therefore `S = abcd101`.

- `d1` is a subset of `01` if and only if `d = 0`.
- `cd` is a subset of `10` if and only if `d = 0` but we already knew that.
- `bc` is a subset of `d1` if and only if `b <= d`
- `ab` is a subset of `cd` if and only if `a <= c and b <= d`

Then these bits relate in a similar way as before, but with the roles of even and odd bits swapped.

---

A shorter solution was found by someone else:

```
bool is_alternating(uint32_t x)
{
    uint32_t y = x << 2;
    return (x | y) <= (y | 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea about

`(n & (n>>1)) == 0` would only check if there is consecutive 1.

You also need to check that every 2 bits are set:

- With `n | (n >> 1u)`, you should have contiguous bits set if it is the case
- adding 1 to previous result would make it a power of 2 (or 0 with overflow)
- `n & (n-1)` is a way to remove least signifiant (rightmost) set bit of `n` (and doing that on power of 2 result in 0)

For edge cases

- for `0`, `(0+1)` is power of 2.
- for `0b101010..10`, we result to `0xFFFF..FF + 1` == `0`, which also give all bits unset :)

Resulting to:

```
constexpr bool is_alternative_bit(std::uint32_t n)
{
    const bool has_consecutive1 = (n & (n >> 1u)) != 0;
    const auto less_signifiant_bit_cleared = [](auto n){ return n & (n - 1u); };

    return !has_consecutive1 && (less_signifiant_bit_cleared((n | (n >> 1u)) + 1u) == 0);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fsPYrrqMe)

Comment: Very nice. I had to look up the `n & (n-1)` thing. I like the way [@sai Charan said it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49476825/22193627): "The expression `n = n & (n - 1)` is a bitwise operation which replaces the rightmost '1' bit in `n` with '0'" Since powers of 2 are the only integers with a single '1', they are the only numbers that are sent to zero by this operation. You got my up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I wrote before seeing the clever use of `n & (n - 1)` by @Jarod42 in his answer.

Ultimately, my solution fails, because it violates the O(1) spec, by running a loop across the bits of `n`. (See function `mask_leading_zeros` below.)

The one thing my solution does have going for it is readability. It starts with a constant composed of alternating bits:

```cpp
    std::uint32_t const alt{ 0b0101'0101'0101'0101'0101'0101'0101'0101 };
```

Count 'em up. There are 16 ones and 16 zeros.

Taking the complement, `~alt`, produces the only other 32-bit integer with alternating bits.

Next, I create a `mask` with zeros in the places where leading zeros appear in `n`, and ones everywhere else.

```cpp
    auto const mask{ mask_leading_zeros(n) };
```

This mask can be used to mask off what should be leading zeros in `alt` and `~alt`. If `n` is composed of alternating bits, then `n` must be either `alt & mask` or `~alt & mask`.

These observations lead to the following function:

```cpp
bool has_alternating_bits(std::uint32_t const n) {
    std::uint32_t const alt{ 0b0101'0101'0101'0101'0101'0101'0101'0101 };
    auto const mask{ mask_leading_zeros(n) };
    return (alt & mask) == n || (~alt & mask) == n;
}
```

Like I said, nice and readable. Of course, I did violate spec when I wrote `mask_leading_zeros`:

```cpp
std::uint32_t mask_leading_zeros(std::uint32_t const n) {
    std::uint32_t mask{};
    for (std::uint32_t bit_number{ 32u }; bit_number--;) {
        auto const bit{ 1u << bit_number };
        if (n & bit)
            break;
        mask |= bit;
    }
    return ~mask;
}
```

Here is the complete of the program I used for testing:

```cpp
// main.ixx
export module main;
import std;

std::uint32_t mask_leading_zeros(std::uint32_t const n) {
    std::uint32_t mask{};
    for (std::uint32_t bit_number{ 32u }; bit_number--;) {
        auto const bit{ 1u << bit_number };
        if (n & bit)
            break;
        mask |= bit;
    }
    return ~mask;
}
bool has_alternating_bits(std::uint32_t const n) {
    std::uint32_t const alt{ 0b0101'0101'0101'0101'0101'0101'0101'0101 };
    auto const mask{ mask_leading_zeros(n) };
    return (alt & mask) == n || (~alt & mask) == n;
}
std::string bit_string(std::uint32_t const n) {
    return std::format("{:b}", n);
}
export int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("{:>5}  {}  {} \n"
        , 'n'
        , '*'
        , "bit_string(n)"
    );
    for (std::uint32_t n{}; n <= 10; ++n)
        std::cout << std::format("{:5}  {}  {} \n"
            , n
            , (has_alternating_bits(n) ? '*' : ' ')
            , bit_string(n)
        );
    for (std::uint32_t const& n : { 20u, 21u, 42u, 43u, 84u, 85u, 170u, 171u, 340u, 341u})
        std::cout << std::format("{:5}  {}  {} \n"
            , n
            , (has_alternating_bits(n) ? '*' : ' ')
            , bit_string(n)
        );
}
// end file: main.ixx
```

Output:

```
    n  *  bit_string(n)
    0  *  0
    1  *  1
    2  *  10
    3     11
    4     100
    5  *  101
    6     110
    7     111
    8     1000
    9     1001
   10  *  1010
   20     10100
   21  *  10101
   42  *  101010
   43     101011
   84     1010100
   85  *  1010101
  170  *  10101010
  171     10101011
  340     101010100
  341  *  101010101
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer
It was quite simple

```
    return (n & (n>>1)) == 0;
```

Comment: What result will this give if n == 0?

Comment: This would return true e.g. for `100` or `1000` - in fact, for any number that doesn't have two consecutive ones.

Comment: Changing and to xor might produce the correct result though you'll presumably need to mask off the high bits